# A book of probability puzzles

Tags: probability, reference-request, recreational-mathematics

I would like to train some recreational probability (Puzzles).

Does any of you know a good collection? Preferably with hints or answers.

I've been studying quite a bit of probability theory, but I don't suspect that will do me any real good.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you seeking something in particular? How would you differentiate these problems from, say, typical textbook problems on probability?

Comment: Typical textbook problems on probability are, in my experience, created to grow accustomed to theory or theorems. What I want are brain teasers I guess made out of curiosity or to tease the brain. I know the difference is delicate, but I hope you get the point.

Comment: http://www.springer.com/mathematics/probability/book/978-0-387-73511-5 p.s. the blog http://8foxes.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Expected%20value has a few good puzzles

Comment: That book looks absolutely perfect! Thanks! If anyone of you know any more I bet those 40 problems will run out at some point :)

Comment: @Henrik in case you're still looking, here's a probability puzzle android app I made:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=atorch.statspuzzles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a book, [Fifty Challenging Problems in Probability With Solutions](http://books.google.com/books/about/Fifty_Challenging_Problems_in_Probabilit.html?id=QiuqPejnweEC) by Frederick Mosteller which is quite a good read.
You can look up this [blog](http://bayesianthink.blogspot.com/) which has a good list of puzzles worked out.

Comment: I've corrected the title and added a link to the book you mentioned. Check to make sure I got the right book.

Comment: That looks like a great suggestion! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

definitely agree that Mosteller's book is excellent. In case you exhaust that, there's also quite a few problems in the recreational vein in: Challenging Mathematical Problems with Elementary Solutions, Volume I: Combinatorial Analysis and Probability Theory.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Challenging-Mathematical-Problems-Elementary-Solutions/dp/0486655369

Have just bought this myself actually for some recreational amusement.

Possibly the ultimate compendium of problems is Grimmett and Stirzaker's volme:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Thousand-Exercises-Probability-Geoffrey-Grimmett/dp/0198572212/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1427198901&sr=1-1&keywords=one+thousand+exercises+in+probability

If you've done all of those, you've pretty much done it all!

Good luck.